# how to convert quote from utf8 to iso in php?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf8-decode

I want to convert some text from utf-8 to iso-8859-1 (in PHP) so I do this:

```
$message_iso = utf8_decode($message_utf8);
```

It works pretty well for é or ô but not for the simple quote ' which is replace by a ? .
How can I make it work?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you converting *to* an ancient, legacy encoding?

Comment: Legacy? I don't know. How do you do this?

Comment: ISO-8859-* are legacy encodings. I don't do this, I use UTF-8.

Comment: With utf8, if I send a mail to a hotmail address, there's encoding problem in the subject of the mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) for this:

```
$message_iso = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $message_utf8);
```

Comment: Of course but I had to WAIT 10min to accept it (wtf?) then I forgot :p

Comment: I still have a problem... when I check my mails with the iOS Mail app, the é is replaced but an ugly char with 1/2 and a kind of arrow